# Finding the index of each character in a substring

Tags: java, string, indexing, substring

I feel like my logic is decent here; I don't feel like I'm completely lost. However, I do know what exactly I'm doing wrong. I can always find the index of the start of the substring, but I can never find the full count (ex. 3,4,5,6) of the index of whatever word the user enters as the substring.

I have been struggling with this for about a week trying to figure out how to do it on my own, I can't get it right.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class midterm
{
    public static void main (String[] args)

    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String simplePhrase;
        String portionPhrase;
        int portionIndex;
        int portionCount;
        int portionIndexTotal;

        System.out.println("Enter a simple phrase:");
        simplePhrase = keyboard.nextLine();

        int phraseLength = simplePhrase.length();
        System.out.println("Phrase length:" +phraseLength);

        System.out.println("Enter a portion of previous phrase:");
        portionPhrase = keyboard.nextLine();

        String portionPhraseSub = simplePhrase.substring(portionPhrase);

        portionIndex = simplePhrase.indexOf(portionPhraseSub);

        for (portionIndex; portionIndex <= portionPhrase; portionIndex++)
        {
            System.out.println("Portion phrase index:"+portionIndex);
        }
     }  
}
```

Comment: `portionIndex <= portionPhrase` doesn't make much sense when the type of `portionPhrase` is `String`... (The code would also be easier to read if you declared the variables at the point of their first use.)

Comment: Please post something that compiles. This `String portionPhraseSub = simplePhrase.substring(portionPhrase);` will not compile.

Comment: What does `simplePhrase.substring(portionPhrase)` even mean when `portionPhrase` is a String?

Comment: You haven't directly asked a question. I guess maybe it is: "What is wrong with my code?" or "Can you fix my code?". Folks on this site tend to respond better when you present a specific problem

Comment: I guess, my question is one i get my code to compile, How would I go about counting every single letter of my substring?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still confused on what you want. There are just two simple things to know and you seem to be making this more complicated than it needs to be.

To get the index of a single character, such as "c" in the word "acorn", you would do this:

```
String s = "acorn";
int cIndex = s.indexOf("c");
System.out.println("The index of c is: " + cIndex);
```

If you want to see if the string contains a chunk, you use the exact same method. So if we are looking at the word "acorn" again and you want to see where "orn" happens, you'd do this:

```
String s = "acorn";
int ornIndex = s.indexOf("orn");
System.out.println("The index of orn is: " + ornIndex);
```

Remember that indexes start from 0 in java, so the index of "a" in "acorn" is 0, of "c" is 1, of "o" is 2, and so on.

I hope that helps. Good luck :)

EDIT: You just commented this:
"I guess, my question is one i get my code to compile, How would I go about counting every single letter of my substring?"

I'll answer that as best as I can, though again, that still is a confusing question.

What do you even mean by count" every letter? If you want to break your word into individual letters, you can do something like this:

```
String s = "acorn";
char[] characters = new char[s.length()-1];
for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
    char[i] = s.charAt(i);
}
```

But I have no clue why you'd want to do that...you can always access any character in a string at a given index with STRING.charAt(index), or if you want to have a String result, STRING.substring(index, index+1)

Comment: The first one makes sense to me however for the second example wouldn't it just print out "ordIndex" = 0, sense it only prints the start of the index? I want to count the index 0 1 2 and print out orn has an index of 0 1 2 that is what im having trouble with

Comment: Well try it. The second one would print out ornIndex = 2, because that is where "orn" happens

Comment: But "orn" doesn't have an index of 0 1 2. If you want to do...I don't even know why this is your question. indexes are indexes. A single instance has one index. Just because it is length of 3, it doesn't mean that each character in that substring is a new index.

Comment: If you really wanted to print out each character in the substring and it's index, just get the index of the string you're looking for with int index = String.indexOf("orn") and then print out index, index + 1, index + 2, since it has a length of 3. but this makes NO sense. It is not the right way to look at indexes.

Comment: It was simply just to practice using IndexOf and String is all, no particular reason. thanks guys I understand it makes no sense was just curious to how I'd go about doing it.

Comment: Sure. If the answer helped you, feel free to give it an uparrow and mark it as an accepted answer so it can help others, too.